# Cant get input from HTML txtbox going to JS w/ API

Tags: javascript, html

I am testing API calls from HTML textbox going to JS. How can you get input HTML going to JS and insert it to the URL?

(change var city to textbox from HTML) I need to add the textbox input to the JS query API URL + textbox.textbox1 + API URL

HTML code:

```html
<head>

<meta charset = "UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="x-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>API</title>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src = "script.js">


</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>


<body>
<div class="weather-container">
<img class ="icon">
<p class="weather"> </p>
<p class="temp"></p>


</div>
<form action="/url" method="GET">

<p>Insert City:</p>
<input type ="text" name="city" id="citytext" placeholder="City">
<button type = "submit" id="btn1" name = "submit">Submit</button>


</form>

</body>
```

Here is the JS

```js
var city = "New York"


$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "&units=imperial&appid=0dcc391bac34298837f2047642794ee3", function(data){

console.log(data)

var icon ="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
var temp = Math.floor(data.main.temp);
var weather = data.weather[0].main;

$('.icon').attr('src', icon);
$('.weather').append(weather);
$('.temp').append(temp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `click` event listener on the `submit` button, also you need to turn its `type` to `button` to not reload the page, and then instead of use hardcoded `city` name, you get it from the `input` value.

```js
const cityInput = document.getElementById('citytext');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('btn1');



submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
$.getJSON("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityInput.value + "&units=imperial&appid=0dcc391bac34298837f2047642794ee3", function(data){


var icon ="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + data.weather[0].icon + ".png";
var temp = Math.floor(data.main.temp);
var weather = data.weather[0].main;
console.log(weather)
$('.icon').attr('src', icon);
$('.weather').append(weather);
$('.temp').append(temp);
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="weather-container">
<img class ="icon">
<p class="weather"> </p>
<p class="temp"></p>


</div>
<form>

<p>Insert City:</p>
<input type ="text" name="city" id="citytext" placeholder="City">
<button type = "button" id="btn1" name = "submit">Submit</button>


</form>

</body>
```